# How Do I Create Substring From Mutating String

Tags: iphone, ios, string, nsarray, substring

I'm a noob to iphone development and I am trying to create a substring from a NSString value that will always change.  Basically, I'm trying to substring the last section of a string that will vary. The string is formatted "March 15 PM Metals Commentary: John Jones" I want the last name part of the string  For example, "Jones" not "John Jones". The two approaches i have attempted either give me exception or return no value.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

```
//This approach throw index out of bounds exception
NSString * storyLink2 = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
NSRange namestart = [storyLink2 rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *name = [[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(namestart.location +1, name.length - namestart.location+1)];

//This approach return nothing
NSString *name = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
NSArray *thingitems = [name componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
name = [thingitems lastObject];
```

EDIT

```
  NSString *name = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
NSLog(@"myname: %@", name);// <-- Showing  "March 15 PM Metals Commentary: John Jones"
NSArray *thingitems = [name componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]; ////<-- [__NSArrayM componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89741a0
NSArray *lastName=[thingitems componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
name = [lastName lastObject];
NSLog(@"myname: %@", name);
```

LOG

```
2013-03-17 01:30:39.738 GSCC[704:207] myname: March 15 PM Metals Commentary: Thomas Vitiello

2013-03-17 01:30:39.739 GSCC[704:207] -[__NSArrayM componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89741a0
2013-03-17 01:30:39.741 GSCC[704:207] Exception - -[__NSArrayM componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89741a0
```

Comment: If the name always comes after the `:` then split the string on the `:` and take the part after that.

Comment: I only want the last name, not the first name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string is `"March 15 PM Metals Commentary: John Jones"` and you always wnat names that comes in last part after a colon **":"** then :

```
NSString *str=@"March 15 PM Metals Commentary: John Jones";
//use storyLink2 in place of str
NSString *name=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@":"][1];
```

EDIT:

If you want only last name : then

```
NSString *str=@"March 15 PM Metals Commentary: John Jones";
//use storyLink2 in place of str
NSArray *fullname=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSArray *lastName=[fullname lastObject];
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I only want Jones, not John Jones

Comment: I'm getting an unrecognized selector error now with this approach

Comment: Do storyLink2  contains full strng as ""March 15 PM Metals Commentary: John Jones"?

Comment: yes, it is showing "March 15 PM Metals Commentary: John Jones" in my Log

Comment: Which line shows unrecoz selector? which compiler/xcode version?

Comment: are you sure name is a single string or it contains objects. i.e. it is an array, as per the error

Comment: Hmm. name is initialized with value from NSMutableArray, as per = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"].  Would that cause problem?

Comment: Amazing error. I need your project. Or at last have a try with this `NSString *name = [[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"] copy];` find my email id in profile.

Comment: Somehow, whitespace was being added after the lastname, as per the white space in my log.  I got the object before the last object and got it working.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the last word in `string`, try `[ [ string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[ NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet ] ] lastObject ]`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested with this without error

```
NSString *string = @"March 15 PM Metals Commentary: John Jones";
NSString *lastName = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@",lastName);
```

So I think your's might be like this?

```
NSString *name = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
NSString *lastName=[[name componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] lastObject];
NSLog(@"myname: %@", lastName);
```